# i have repeating contents want to to be on the columns

Tags: css, html

here is my html code

```
<style>
.topicdiv1{width:340px}
</style>

<div>
<? foreach($rows as $row): ?>
    <div class="topicdiv1"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></div>
<? endforeach; ?>
   </div>
```

as my full page is about 800px width and here it will take only 340px width and 
each will come after or bellow next one i want it side by side not break after each 
div it is posible

**no like this**

```
 __________
|          |
|__________|
 __________
|          |
|__________|
```

**but like this**

```
 __________     ___________
|          |   |           |
|__________|   |___________|
```

**as here i have many conenct and mean rows so i need tow side by side and then break not
after each one break line**

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can make the div elements inline-blocks

```
.topicdiv1{width:340px; display: inline-block}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one use modulus with count of loop iteration and check if 0 then open new container which will contain the next two divs in it

```
 <style>
    .topicdiv1{width:340px; float:left;}
    .main_content{width:800px}
    </style>

    <div>  <div class="main_content">
    <? $i=1;
     foreach($rows as $row): ?>

        <div class="topicdiv1"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></div>
if($i%2 == 0){
    echo '</div>  <div class="main_content">' ;
    }

    <? 
 $i++;
endforeach; ?>
       </div>
     </div>
```

OR simply play with css

```
 <style>
    .topicdiv1{width:340px; float:left;}        
 </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed as others ppl said, I will go with css property.
Either add display:inline-block OR float: left.

Personnaly I would use display inline block.